# Email string parsing using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to do a complicated (to me) regex on a multi-line snip from an e-mail. I have tried hard, with no luck. I am trying to get rid of anything from "On " through " wrote:"

Would be nice if you can also check to see if it contains the word "AcmeCompany", so it doesn't check for everything "On " "wrote:"

So far, I have this: `/On(.*)AcmeCompany(.*)/im` but it does not work...

```
say hello, world!

On Tue, Jun 7, 2011 at 6:18 AM, AcmeCompany <
24a95f49f7ce573fds2d+c@AcmeCompany.com> wrote:
```

Thank you for the responses, but it seems like there's another problem.

**EDIT**: I found out that this works: `/On[\s\S]+?AcmeCompany[\s\S]+?wrote:/m`, but it seems to fail when the e-mail contents have word "On".

```
say hello, world!

On a plane!    

On Tue, Jun 7, 2011 at 6:18 AM, AcmeCompany <
24a95f49f7ce573fds2d+c@AcmeCompany.com> wrote:
```

**EDIT2**: Every mail client is different... gmail tends to do it in 2 lines, mail app from iphone do it in 1 line, so it doens't always follow the strict format.

1 thing for sure: beginning always uses "On " and ends with " wrote:". It also contains a hash and AcmeCompany, which I can also use to verify.

Comment: You don't need to capture the `.*`, try `On.*AcmeCompany.*`

Comment: `.` won't catch a newline, which is why you are having trouble with a regex that spans more than one line.

Comment: @Michael Pryor : I tried using \sm instead of \im, i got pretty close, but when I have `On blah blah On Tues Jun 7,` it breaks..

Comment: Hi, please try once using /On[\s\S]+?AcmeCompany[\s\S]+?wrote:/

Comment: @sudimail I revised the question, your solution works, but it ran another problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new requirement I am adding another reply. Hope you won't mind.

<strike>Can you try something like this?</strike>

```
/On\s(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)[\s\S]+?AcmeCompany[\s\S]+?wrote:/
```

I am trying again..how about using ?

```
/On.+?AcmeCompany[\s\S]+?wrote:/
```

Comment: I am modifying here, as, but again if the content has day name! trying to think!

Comment: it turns out not every mail client includes mon/tue/wed... but every mail client includes "On" and "wrote:" so this would only work for gmail and hotmail. :(

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
/On[\s\S]+?AcmeCompany[\s\S]+?wrote:/
```

The regular expression above first matches `On` and then either of `all spaces` and `non-spaces` (together swallowing all characters and newlines) with a lazy repetition mode till it finds `AcmeCompany`. Again it matches `all spaces` and `non-spaces` (together swallowing all characters and newlines) with a lazy repetition till it finds `wrote:`

Comment: Hi, this actually works, but it seems like it collects anything "On" and thereafter...

Answer (score 1):

To get the string before `On Tue,Jun`...:

```
$str = explode ('On', $yourstring);
$oldstr = array_pop($str); //Remove the last value of the $str array
echo trim( implode('On',$str) ); //Trim the string to remove any unnecessary line breaks
```

To find if the hidden message contains `AcmeCompany`:

```
if( strstr ( $oldstr , 'AcmeCompany' ) ) {
    echo "I found AcmeCompany!";
} else {
    echo "I didn't find AcmeCompany!";
}
```

Hope my answer is useful, even though I didn't use regex.

Comment: Hi, interesting concept.. If we happen to have "On" anywhere in the body, then this solution won't work... last resort, I might crop out 2 rows

Comment: Yes, but this shows that your script would break if someone's comment was: `say hello, world!

On Tue, Jun 7, 2011 at 6:18 AM, Hacker <hacker@hacker> wrote:`

Comment: That's also true... perhaps it's better to crop out last 2 rows.. However, this is highly unlikely to happen =/

Comment: I gotta give credit to you (+1), but it still doesn't fit the requirement. If the sender has bunch of "On" then it won't work.

Comment: Well, during *my* tests, it worked, because the `array_pop` function removes the last value (the comment you want to delete) and keeps the others.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
On.*AcmeCompany.*
```

---

Maybe offtopic but...
If you want to learn regex you should try [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

Example of Expresso at work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/On.*AcmeCompany <$[^:]+:/im`, the `m` is important as it lets the `$` match line breaks.